# setCornerRadius: causes flickering in NSTableView

Tags: macos, cocoa, quartz-graphics

I'm using a view based NSTableView which displays a NSTableRowView containing an NSImageView and some NSTextFields. The NSTextFields are having the backgroundColor property set and are drawing correctly. I've tried to draw them with rounded corners by setting

```
[textfield.layer setWantsLayer: YES];
[textfield.layer setCornerRadius: 5.];
```

What is working but causes the views with the applied corner radius to flicker while scrolling the table view. Setting the view's layer via textfield.layer `[setLayer: [CALayer layer]]` or forcing the layer to rasterize by setting `[textfield.layer setShouldRasterize: YES]` also did not work. Any suggestions how to get rid of the nasty flickering?
I'm developing on Mavericks for Mavericks using Xcode 5.

Comment: Try turning off smooth scrolling.

Comment: Thanks, coming from iOS development everything on Mac is not that neat :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

With the help of [uchuugaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1722462/uchuugaka)'s post I was able to fix it using this tutorial: [Tutorial](http://www.jwilling.com/optimized-scrolling-in-nstableview/)

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer: ... Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.